# Unity after LoadScene() and lighting and rendering not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

This is the scene before the LoadScene() everything is normal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UM4y.png)

And, after I collected all the yellow item I win the game and I click the GUI.button to try again (load the scene again)
the scene is wraped like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nXIa.png)

And I get an error in my lighting component like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bX7m.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue shouldn't occur in a build. In the Editor, however, it unfortunately occurs for unknown reasons. To resolve the issue, you can go to **Window-Rendering-Lighting** and click the **Bake**/**Generate Lighting**/**Build** button at the bottom. If the button is greyed out, you need to deselect the **Auto** option next to the button.

Comment: Yes! That did works!! THX!! And it does only occur in the editor not after building,THX for helping.